# Comparing two strings containing number at the end

Tags: excel, comparison, excel-formula, worksheet-function, excel-2013

I have two cells (A2 and B2) in Excel that have the same value 'GDF5'. But when I compare the values of the two cells using

```
=IF(A2=B2, 1, 0)
```

the value returned is `0`. And when I use the EXACT function to compare

```
=EXACT(A2,B2)
```

it returns `FALSE`.

Why is this happening? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are there leading or trailing spaces in either cell, what do you get with `=TRIM(A2)=TRIM(B2)`?

Comment: .....also, perhaps check the formatting of the cells.....

Comment: It worked using `=TRIM(A2)=TRIM(B2)`

Answer (score 0):

Your test with TRIM indicates that one or other has spaces that the other does not - the cells do not have the same contents - so naturally EXACT returns `FALSE`. Also since they are not equal the IF test is not passed hence the 'else' result returned.